# Machine Learning - How to compare two models?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, logistic-regression

I am working on loan eligibility supervised project. I used logistic regression and a support vector machine as two models. For the logistic regression, accuracy is 0.84 and the loss function is 0.45. For SVM accuracy is 0.80 and loss function is 0.33. Which of these algorithms performs better? How do we compare two models (by the accuracy or by loss function)?

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you want to choose between accuracy and loss [this will help you](https://kharshit.github.io/blog/2018/12/07/loss-vs-accuracy). However, for classification problem it's usually to use area under the ROC curve for Binary classification or the F1 score when you have many classes. It'll help you to have control on the recall and precision [see here for more details](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A9cision_et_rappel).